# Jquery - Targeting elements that have been changed after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, raspberry-pi

I have not been able to find any discussion of what I'm struggling with on this site or any other, but perhaps I'm not asking the right question. I'm working on a web interface for a wireless speaker powered by the raspberry pi, and (as I inherited it) almost all the POST requests are done with calls to `$.ajax.` `$().ready()` is as follows:

```
    $().ready(function (){
        $(document).ajaxStart(function (){ 
            $.blockUI({ message: '<img id="loadimg" src="img/loading.gif" width="64"  />'}); 
        }).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

    $("nav.setup-nav a").not("[target='_blank']").on("click", function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href=$(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:href,
            success:function (data){
                $(".contentPanel").html(data);
                $(this).blur();
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:100, scrollLeft:400}, 600);
                },
            });
            return false;
        }); 
    });
```

Which forces all the content of the linked-to pages in the nav menu to load inside a div in the center of the page. That is, except for pages with `target="_blank"` attribute. This is so `event.preventDefault` and the UI blocking stuff doesn't get called when linking to an external page that we want to load in a new window. I'll try to concisely describe my issue: One of the menu items is (conditionally) a link to a web-based MPD client, which we definitely do NOT want to load inside a div on the same page, and thus has `target="_blank"` attribute. The problem is the user can also choose to enable or disable the MPD daemon through the web-interface. PHP handles the setting of all these kinds of state variables. Basically like this:

```
    if ($config->is_flag_set($MPD_FLAG))
    { 
        echo '<li><a target="_blank" id="mpd" href="rompr/">Local Playback Web Interface</a></li>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li><a id="mpd" href="local-disabled.php">Local Playback Web Interface</a></li>';
    }
```

and so when the page first loads, if the MPD daemon is not running the link to the web interface is pointed to a page that explains MPD is not enabled. This link does NOT contain the `target="_blank"` attribute. However, if one navigates to the settings form and switches on MPD, there is logic to replace the href and target attributes of that particular link, so theoretically all should work as if the page had loaded initially with the MPD flag on (if that is clear!). The problem is that when the "replaced" link with `target="_blank"` (set by `.prop()` or `.attr()`, I've tried both and it doesn't seem to make a difference) is clicked, the page still loads inside the div!I tried duplicating the click handler that's defined within `$().ready` and putting it in another function which I call after the link attributes are set, but it still doesn't work as I imagine it should! Just to verify that I wasn't crazy, I used `.each()` to print all the links that did and did not have the `target="_blank"` attribute and that all corresponds to what I believe it should be. Why is the replaced link not getting treated as if it has a `target="_blank"` attribute in the click handler? By the way, Going the other way and removing the `target="_blank"` attribute if MPD is turned off, works like a charm. Thanks so much in advance for any answers, and my apologies if I have duplicated a previous question!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are always tricky anytime you have to reload elements with ajax. The best way I've found is to attach the event to some container element that will not reload:

```
$('#always_present_container').on('click', "nav.setup-nav a", function (event){
    if($(this).attr('target') != '_blank'){
        ...
    }

});
```

that way the element is checked for the attribute when its container is clicked. When you set up $('element').click() the selector is checked on the page load and the events attached then, so when you reload something via ajax the new element doesn't get this event attached.

Note: normally you could avoid the conditional statement in the function, but I didn't know of an easy way to filter by target in a css selector.

Comment: Thats the ticket. Now I feel foolish - the parent nav element is never changed anyway, I just forgot that you can pass a selector argument to `.on()`! Thanks!